# Matplotlib change x-axis unit

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Currently, I am using matplotlib to plot charts from pandas. But when I plot, I get the resultant chart's x-axis in months. I want to change it to daily and hourly basis. How can I achieve it?

**My Dataset:**

```
Recorded Time          Count       
2019-08-01 00:10:00      3
2019-08-01 00:20:00      5
2019-08-01 00:30:00      0
2019-08-01 00:40:00      5
2019-08-01 00:50:00      9
and so on...
```

**Getting Index:**

```
people = people.set_index('Recorded Time')
people.index
```

Here people is pandas dataframe

**Index Output:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-01 00:10:00', '2019-08-01 00:20:00',
               '2019-08-01 00:30:00', '2019-08-01 00:40:00',
               '2019-08-01 00:50:00', '2019-08-01 01:00:00',
               '2019-08-01 01:10:00', '2019-08-01 01:20:00',
               '2019-08-01 01:30:00', '2019-08-01 01:40:00',
               ...
               '2019-12-17 19:50:00', '2019-12-17 20:00:00',
               '2019-12-17 20:10:00', '2019-12-17 20:20:00',
               '2019-12-17 20:30:00', '2019-12-17 20:40:00',
               '2019-12-17 20:50:00', '2019-12-17 21:00:00',
               '2019-12-17 21:10:00', '2019-12-17 21:20:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Recorded Time', length=20000, freq=None)
```

**Mean:**

```
y = people['Count'].resample(rule='24H').mean()
```

**Mean Output**

```
Recorded Time
2019-08-01    37.384615
2019-08-02    35.805556
2019-08-03    34.298611
2019-08-04    36.833333
2019-08-05    35.340278
2019-08-06    36.854167
2019-08-07    35.180556
2019-08-08    35.979167
2019-08-09    34.847222
2019-08-10    36.381944
2019-08-11    36.006944
2019-08-12    35.041667
2019-08-13    36.201389
2019-08-14    35.291667
2019-08-15    35.041667
2019-08-16    34.944444
2019-08-17    35.826389
2019-08-18    37.347222
2019-08-19    34.312500
2019-08-20    33.472222
2019-08-21    33.743056
2019-08-22    35.243056
2019-08-23    36.819444
2019-08-24    35.145833
2019-08-25    35.069444
2019-08-26    33.875000
2019-08-27    35.111111
2019-08-28    34.590278
2019-08-29    35.826389
2019-08-30    36.381944
                ...    
2019-11-18    34.395833
2019-11-19    35.527778
2019-11-20    35.798611
2019-11-21    34.361111
2019-11-22    36.062500
2019-11-23    35.298611
2019-11-24    34.187500
2019-11-25    35.020833
2019-11-26    34.465278
2019-11-27    35.729167
2019-11-28    34.715278
2019-11-29    34.173611
2019-11-30    34.812500
2019-12-01    39.638889
2019-12-02    35.000000
2019-12-03    36.479167
2019-12-04    35.868056
2019-12-05    34.798611
2019-12-06    37.916667
2019-12-07    33.972222
2019-12-08    32.958333
2019-12-09    35.361111
2019-12-10    35.673611
2019-12-11    35.041667
2019-12-12    36.965278
2019-12-13    35.805556
2019-12-14    36.638889
2019-12-15    36.027778
2019-12-16    36.263889
2019-12-17    38.558140
Freq: 24H, Name: Count, Length: 139, dtype: float64
```

Finally, plotting the data:

```
y.plot(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the DateFormatter on your xaxis.

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter


myFmt = DateFormatter("%d")  # Day format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: How should I use this in my current plot : y.plot(figsize=(15, 6))

Comment: Could you edit your main post with a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example